# Random url and title with php

Tags: php

I am using the code bellow to get random video and i need to add a title also. Each video url must have a title also

Any suggestion?

```
<?php 
$video_array = array 
('http://www.youtube.com/embed/rMNNDINCFHg', 
'http://www.youtube.com/embed/bDF6DVzKFFg', 
'http://www.youtube.com/embed/bDF6DVzKFFg'); 
shuffle($video_array);
$video = $video_array[0]; 
?>

<iframe width='1006' height='421' src='<?php echo $video; ?>' title='TITLE HERE' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Regards
Irene

Comment: So what are you looking for? Can you elaborate?

Comment: then add a tittle in the array for each video and done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store the tile in the array and print it -

```
<?php 
$video_array = array(
array('url' => 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/rMNNDINCFHg', 'title' => 'ABC'),
array('url' => 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/bDF6DVzKFFg', 'title' => 'DSF'),
array('url' => 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/bDF6DVzKFFg', 'title' => 'RYUY')
); 
shuffle($video_array);
$video = $video_array[0]; 
?>

<iframe width='1006' height='421' src='<?php echo $video['url']; ?>' title='<?php echo $video['title']; ?>' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```